# Return 4 list from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to return 4 diffrent lists from AsyncTask as result , I have used Pair class to test to return two only, I think Maybe there is problem in Pair class

but it gives ERROR:

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hesham.sams/com.hesham.sams.ListActivity1}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106)
    at com.hesham.sams.ListActivity1.getNames(ListActivity1.java:130)
    at com.hesham.sams.ListActivity1.onCreate(ListActivity1.java:48)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
    ... 11 more
```

My pair class :

```
 public class Pair {

public List<Student> StudentNamesList;
public List<Student> StudentIdList;

public void setids(List<Student> StudentNamesList) {
    this.StudentNamesList = StudentNamesList;
}

public void setnames(List<Student> StudentIdList) {
    this.StudentIdList = StudentIdList;
}

public List<Student> getids() {
    return this.StudentNamesList;
}

public List<Student> getnames() {
    return this.StudentIdList;
}
}
```

My AsyncTask class :

```
public class GetListAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Pair> {

private Activity activity;
private  ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Context context;

public GetListAsync(Activity activity, ProgressDialog progressDialog, 
                                                    Context context) {
    super();
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.context = context;
}


    ArrayList<Student> StudentIdList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    ArrayList<Student> StudentNamesList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Pair p = new Pair();

@Override
protected Pair doInBackground(Void... voids) {

// here getting some strings from database it's ok ,
// then assigne it to my studentidlist
    StudentIdList.add(get(String.valueOf(2)));
        p.setids(StudentNamesList);
    } catch (Exception e) { 
    }   

//Here is Second list 
 StudentIdList.add(get(String.valueOf(2)));

// here getting some strings from database it's ok ,
// then     assigne it to my studentidlist
p.setids(StudentIdList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

 return p ;
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Pair p) {
        GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonb.create();
        String json = gson.toJson(p.getnames());
```

ListActivity Method for just One method :

```
    public List<Student> getNames() {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    String result = prefs.getString("studentnames", null);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(result).getAsJsonArray();

    ArrayList<Student> lcs = new ArrayList<Student>();

    for (JsonElement obj : Jarray) {
        Student cse = gson.fromJson(obj, Student.class);
        lcs.add(cse);
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lcs.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return (List<Student>) lcs;

} // end of on create
```

UPDATE

Here is my JSON Set in AsyncTask onPostExecute

```
GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonb.create();
    String json = gson.toJson(p.getids());
```

Here us my JSON Get in Listview Activity class :

```
    public List<Student> getNames() {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    String result = prefs.getString("studentnames", null);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(result).getAsJsonArray();

    ArrayList<Student> lcs = new ArrayList<Student>();

    for (JsonElement obj : Jarray) {
        Student cse = gson.fromJson(obj, Student.class);
        lcs.add(cse);
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lcs.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return (List<Student>) lcs;
```

NOTE : when using this it works but i want to use all my 4 lists :

```
String json = gson.toJson(StudentIdList);
```

Comment: What is `ListActivity1.java` line 48? You're attempting to parse some string as a JSON array, but it's not.

Comment: listActivity it working OK i was tested it with single list , but i'm sure the problem in Pair class or in AsyncTask Class ,

Comment: Look at the stack trace: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106)
    at com.hesham.sams.ListActivity1.getNames(ListActivity1.java:130)` - clearly, the problem is in method `getNames` of your `ListActivity` class, on line 130.

Comment: i have updated the Q with ListActivity getNames() method code

Comment: And which line is 130 in the file?

Comment: how can a string be parsed as Array :?

Comment: This is not string , this is list of  type Sudent , please refer to Pair class above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you are parsing is not a JSON array

```
JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(result).getAsJsonArray();
```

It would had been helpful to see the JSON , in order to adjust to the right object graph, but try a JSON object instead.

EDIT:

> "It works when I use String json = gson.toJson(StudentIdList);"

It does not work with:

```
String json = gson.toJson(p.getids());
```

because `getids()` does not return the `StudentIdList`

```
public List<Student> getids() {
    return this.StudentNamesList;
}

public List<Student> getnames() {
    return this.StudentIdList;
}
```

So fix it:

```
public List<Student> getids() {
    return this.StudentIdList;
}

public List<Student> getnames() {
    return this.StudentNamesList;
}
```

Comment: plese not when i pass " StudentIdList " it works , but when i pass p.getnames() gets that error

Comment: I have seen the problem , see my update, let me know if you still get errors, we will sort this out

Answer (score 0):

I cite your post:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106)
at com.hesham.sams.ListActivity1.getNames(ListActivity1.java:130)
at com.hesham.sams.ListActivity1.onCreate(ListActivity1.java:48)
```

Look into that code. Most likely, you return something wrong.

Comment: i return p.getnames() from pair class , but i thing that return null?

Comment: Add `Log.d("~~~~","\n\n\n~~~~whatever="+whatever)` and examine the logs.